# Loop will not end despite the terminating expression

Tags: java

Hello Stack overflow community,

My prompt is:
**" You will do error checking to make sure that the hour entered is in the range [0, 23]. Keep asking the user until the user enters a time within the valid range.

My program when it has the correct integer inputs (any int input really) will work correctly. However, if i enter a non-int, then everything is stuck in an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong?

```
   import java.util.*;
public class Tester2 {
    int a; // any valid int number

public void loop() 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=0; // terminating int
    while(x==0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 0-23: ");


            try
            {
                if(sc.hasNextInt()) 
                {
                    a=sc.nextInt();
                    if((a>=0&&a<=23)) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Success! ");
                        x=1;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Retry! ");
                        a=0;
                        x=0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
            {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }

        }

}

}
```

Comment: ah, the famous halting problem.

Comment: Add `sc.nextLine()` to your **`catch`** block. `nextInt` will not consume a token that isn't an `int`.

Comment: If the `Scanner` does not have a next int what will your code do? (Hint: What will your code *not* do?)

Comment: add an `else` block to your `if(sc.hasNextInt())`

Comment: Also, Java has booleans. Use them instead of using integers with 0 and 1 as possible values.

Comment: what do you mean by sc.nextLine()? should it look like this?                    
 catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
            {
                System.out.println("invalid input");                                 
                sc.nextLine()
            }

Comment: I tried using booleans before, but they give me the same problem :(

Comment: @JONATHANTran the javadoc is your friend. sc.nextLine() is calling the nextLine() method on the variable sc, which is of type Scanner. So read the javadoc of this method to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

`sc.hasNextInt()` will return `false` if the next element to be read is not a valid integer.  However, this element is not read at any point in your code in that case.

You should ensure that this element is read and discarded when `sc.hasNextInt()` is false (adding `sc.next()` inside an `else` block should do the trick).